# Using string functions on Alias title using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, structure, alias

I want to name my Alias titles using data from my tables. Here's a totally stupid example to show what I want to do:

`SELECT id AS CONCAT('id_', name)`

Which would give me the output id_5 => 5. (if ID was 5 in the table)

Comment: you would like that example to operate on `id_1` thru `id_5`, correct?  if so checkout pivot tables as Nathan suggests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you're after is a pivot - you mean that for each row in the table, you would end up with a new column, right?  If so, then just google mysql pivot  (sorry, I'm used to sqlserver)

Comment: I don't think so.. I literally just want to rename the Alias. Forget about it being dynamically done for now, can you do: `SELECT id AS CONCAT('i','d')` (not that you'd ever want to)